# What is the code of Trishula in TeX?

Tags: greek, indic, hindi, xgreek, cbgreek

Roughly speaking (of course not exactly);
one can says [trishula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trishula) 
is an indian equivalent of [trident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident); i.e. an indian format of `Psi`.

> What is the command for trishula in TeX or LateX?
>   Also any other format(s) of `Psi` are wellcome!
>   Especially this [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/Manjisai.svg/670px-Manjisai.svg.png)!
>   I only know these formats: `\psi` and `Psi`.

---

Let's clearifying my intention by `any another format`;
for example each of the following are another format's to `C`:
`\mathcal{C}` or `\mathfrak{C}` or `\mathbb{C}`, etc.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think that LateX has such a symbol, although it may exist in some specialised font.

Comment: The `wasysym` package features `\neptune`, and the `marvosym`, `mathabx`, and `starfont` each feature `\Neptune`. Give them a try and see if one of them meets your needs.

Comment: You can use the trident emoji  U+1F531 from a font that supports it.